# Which YAML file is used when a branch triggers the YAMLs pipeline?

Tags: git, yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a YAML file that gets triggered when 'SomeBranch' gets updated

```
trigger:
- SomeBranch

[Various Steps]
```

Now I've updated properties in the YAML file found in 'SomeBranch' and pushed it to my repository stored on Azure Devops. My question is which version of the YAML file will be used when Azures pipeline gets triggered? Will it be the old YAML file found in the master branch or the new updated one in 'SomeBranch'?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the version of the file present in the branch.